# Maven shaded jar used as external project dependency

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-shade-plugin, uberjar

I have used maven shade plugin in my project to relocate all dependency jar classes under one package e.g., org.shade.*

When I try to use that shaded jar in other application as maven dependency it pulls dependency jar's.

My expectation is when uber/shaded jar included as maven dependency it should not pull any other dependent class jar, Since already those classes are repackaged within shaded jar.

Comment: You make a confusion between a maven artifact and the result of the building process of that artifact (a jar or shaded jar). Adding an artifact as dependency to a project is not just a "download the jar" thing, it will analyze the dependency's pom, includes transitive dependencies, eventually also adds sources or tests jar depending on the pom xml, ...

Comment: Show us how you include your shared jar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The classic scenario is:

- A project producing an uber-jar has its own dependencies (`dependency` elements in its `pom.xml` file) which then are packaged together in one uber-jar as Maven artifact
- When using this uber-jar as a dependency (`dependency` element) of another project, Maven would then inspect its `<artifact>-<version>.pom` file (published together with the final artifact into the Maven repository), which is basically a renamed copy of its original `pom.xml` file, where dependencies (`dependency` element) were declared (exactly the dependencies packaged into the uber-jar).
- Since you already have them packed, you would then like to ignore the `.pom` file (and its `dependencies` element), for that you need to add [`exclusions`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) as following:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
      <artifactId>something-uber</artifactId>
      <version>some-version</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>*</groupId>
              <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  ```

Note: the feature above is only available since Maven [**`3.2.1`**](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html).

As such, you are making clear to Maven you don't want any transitive dependency and [Maven dependency mediation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) would then not trigger them.

---

As a side note: this is not a good practice to have an uber-jar as dependency of a project: it will just make maintenance harder since you can't control transitive dependencies via `dependencyManagement` or `dependencies` order of the dependent project. As such you will always need to re-pack the uber jar whenever a dependency (one of its transitive one) would need maintenance (change version and so on) and have much less control on the dependent project (again, harder maintenance).

Answer (score 4):

---

As the pom.xml on your ***source project*** that produces the uber jar declares transitive dependencies, if you include it as dependency into an ***external project*** then Maven will try to get these ( even if these are already included on the uber jar ).

I share a solution that let you avoid to explicitly exclude all transitive dependencies including it into an **external project** as explained by @A_DiMatteo on his solution ( I agree also with him about to avoid to use uber jar as dependency if not strictly necessary to do it for some reason ). As result then you should be able to include your uber jar dependency **without using *exclusions* element** as follow:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>something-uber</artifactId>
  <version>some-version</version>
</dependency>
```

> **Premise**: my goal was to provide both **uber** ( without transitive dependency declared on pom ) and **thin** jars on my repository. So my solution "A" is based on this scenario and currently has the limit that the shaded jar is uploaded 2 times on repository.
>
> - To provide only the **uber** jar see "B" solution below
> - For a possible solution for "A" limit see the **UPDATE** section at the end

### A) Provide both thin and uber jars on repository

1- On your ***source project*** configure on your **something** module pom.xml the following **maven-shade-plugin** as follow:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <finalName>something-uber-${project.version}</finalName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then use the **build-helper-maven-plugin** plugin to attach the new artifact with "uber" classifier on module:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-artifacts</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifacts>
          <artifact>
            <file>
              ${project.build.directory}/something-uber-${project.version}.jar
            </file>
            <classifier>uber</classifier>
          </artifact>
        </artifacts>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will generate as results of the maven install phase the following two jars on *target/* directory:

```
40K something-0.1.0.jar
7M  something-uber-0.1.0.jar
```

> **WARN:** Executing then the maven deploy phase **both jars will be uploaded on repository!** The target here should be to upload only the **thin jar** skipping deploy for **shaded jar** in order to leave it as a local artifact ( See the **UPDATE** section at the end for a possible fix )

2- Create then another module on your **source project** named **something-uber** adding following dependencies and plugin:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>something</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <classifier>uber</classifier>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note the followings on including the dependency:

- the classifier should be equals to **uber** ( the one you've specified attaching new artifact using **build-helper-maven-plugin** on first module )
- the **exclusions** are specified.

Executing at the end the maven deploy phase on this module the shaded jar will be uploaded on repository and you we'll be able to add it as dependency into an **external project** as follow:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
 <artifactId>something-uber</artifactId>
 <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

### B) Provide only uber jar on repository

Starting from solution "A" if you want to avoid to provide the *thin jar* on repository you should avoid on point 1 to specify **finalName** on maven-shade-plugin configuration and so avoid also the  **build-helper-maven-plugin** plugin as there isn't a new artifact to attach.
Doing this, deploying the module you'll have only the uber jar on target/ as default one ( without classifier ):

```
7M  something-0.1.0.jar
```

You should also skip the upload otherwise you'll have also here two fat jars uploaded ( *something-0.1.0.jar* & *something-uber-0.1.0.jar* ).
To do this add the following plugin on the same module:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

At the end on point 2 just avoid to specify the **classifier** on adding the dependency as follow:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>something</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### UPDATE: Skip first shaded jar upload on A) solution

After searching for a solution for a while without success I decided to fork the **maven-deploy-plugin** plugin from GitHub and work for a new feature in order to skip shaded jar created on first module adding the plugin configured as follow:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <configuration>
    <skipAttachedArtifacts>
      <artifact>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>something</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <classifier>uber</classifier>
      </artifact>
    </skipAttachedArtifacts>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

> Currently using the **maven-deploy-plugin** plugin all artifacts are excluded from deploy while target here is to exclude only a specific one. On my fork I've introduced the "skipAttachedArtifacts" configuration parameter in order to specify attached artifacts to exclude from deploy.

Here is the link on my forked project on GitHub:
https://github.com/gregorycallea/maven-deploy-plugin

Here the link instead to the pull request I've submitted  on apache plugin project:
https://github.com/apache/maven-deploy-plugin/pull/3